# Django url pattern - parameter with forward slash

Tags: python, regex, django

How can I create a url pattern for two parameters where the first parameter contains a forward slash as part of its contents:

```
da/ta1=/data2
```

Intially I had the following pattern:

```
(r'^view/(?P<item_id>\w+=)/(?P<changekey>\w+)/$', 'view'),
```

However this pattern does not match because of the first forward slash which is part of the parameter data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you construct the url yourself, you could use [`quote_plus`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote_plus) to encode the inline forward slash:

```
>>> '/'.join([urllib.quote_plus(d) for d in ['da/ta1', 'data2']])
'da%2Fta1/data2'
```

And to decode:

```
>>> urllib.unquote_plus('da%2Fta1/data2')
'da/ta1/data2'
```

To then match your data, your pattern could be changed to the construct found below. For the first parameter, this matches everything up to the `=` character; the second parameter is expected to be alphanumerical.

```
(r'^view/(?P<item_id>[^=]+)=/(?P<changekey>\w+)/$', 'view')
```

Comment: Thanks for that, the only issue I'm having now is that the pattern still isn't matching, how can I get the pattern to include %2F when matching?

Answer (score 1):

Django Admin does have the same problem with slashes in parameters. To fix this, Django uses its own quote function:

```
from django.contrib.admin.utils import quote
quote(param1)
```

In the view itself:

```
unquote(self.kwargs.get('param1'))
```