# How Django accepts forward slash in a string at URL's

Tags: django, django-urls

```
value = "hjhj/dfdfd/dfdll=="
```

I am sending a jQuery request to django like `/me/accept/{{value}}`

**Django URLS:**

```
url(r'^me/accept/(.*)$', 'app.views.function'),
```

The **`(.*)`** regular Expression is not working anymore, means value is not identifying

**The following regular expressions I had tried**

- [^=]+
- .*

I tried so many cases and I failed in the end. Please guide me how django url accepts forward slash with the value as a string

Comment: Django doesn't do anything particular, it just uses standard Python regexes, and there doesn't look to be anything wrong with your regex. Are you sure you are sending the right format? Maybe you should post your jQuery code, plus your full urls.py.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django url pattern - parameter with forward slash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875886/django-url-pattern-parameter-with-forward-slash)

Comment: By "not working anymore" do you mean that app.views.function isn't being called? Or maybe do you mean that you're no longer getting a parameter for the matched value? If it's the second, rewrite `(.*)` as `(?<param_name>.*)`

Comment: @Selcuk I had tried the link earlier what you suggested ..But its not working, then I had post the question in this space

Comment: @dylrei I mean no longer getting a parameter for the matched value

Comment: @dylrei it looks your regular expression is working

Answer (score 1):

Try this syntax, it should work to get the value from URL.`/me/accept/(?P<value>\d+)/$`. The value can be used in your associated view with the variable name `value`. The `d+` means all the characters after slash as the value. Instead of plus sign you can mention a number specifying how many characters you need such as `/me/accept/(?P<id1>\d[2])` for getting 2 characters after slash as the value.