# Django URL regex to include forward slashes

Tags: python, regex, django, url, django-urls

I am having trouble with creating a Django URL regex which allows all characters (including forward slashes). More specifically, the problem I am having is differentiating between forward slashes used in the URL args and forward slashes used as delimiters in the URL.

example:

I have a URL which looks like this:
**localhost:8000/jfe/customer/customerNumb/invoice2/portfolio/**

this consists of 3 URL arguments: 
**customerNumb, 
invoice2, 
portfolio.**

My goal is to make it so argument 2 can contain special characters including '/' so the 2nd argument could be something like "KJ 02/2017" (without quotes).

example:
**localhost:8000/jfe/customer/customerNumb/KJ 02/2017/portfolio/**

in the example of using "KJ 02/2017" I am having trouble with differentiating the '/' in "KJ 02/2017" and the '/' which separates arg2 and arg3.

my regex:

```
url(r'^customer/(?P<customer_number>[0-9]+)/(?P<invoice>[^/]+)/$')
url(r'^customer/(?P<customer_number>[0-9]+)/(?P<invoice>[^/]+)/(?P<portfolio>[^/]+)/$')
```

I have also tried

```
url(r'^customer/(?P<customer_number>[0-9]+)/(?P<invoice>.+)/$')
url(r'^customer/(?P<customer_number>[0-9]+)/(?P<invoice>.+)/(?P<portfolio>[^/]+)/$')
```

If I encode the URL:

example: **localhost:8000/jfe/customer/customerNumb/KJ%2002%2F2017/portfolio/**
the regex will parse it like this:

**arg1:** customerNumb,
**arg2:** KJ%2002%2F2017/portfolio/

when I want:

**arg1:** customerNumb
**arg2:** KJ%2002%2F2017
**arg3:** portfolio

can someone please help me understand where I am messing up in my regex? or let me know if its even possible to have '/' included in url arguments?

thank you

**EDIT:**
it was pointed out that my 2nd attempt works, which is true, but I would like to mention the Django seems to decode the URL before passing it the regex. As a result the regex sees it as this:

**localhost:8000/jfe/customer/customerNumb/KJ 02/2017/portfolio/**

Comment: you shouldn't do that

Comment: if you mean that I shouldnt have '/' in my arguments I agree, but it's a business requirement so not much I can do.

Comment: Your second attempt [seems to work](http://pythex.org/?regex=customer%2F(%3FP%3Ccustomer_number%3E%5B0-9%5D%2B)%2F(%3FP%3Cinvoice%3E.%2B)%2F(%3FP%3Cportfolio%3E%5B%5E%2F%5D%2B)%2F%24&test_string=localhost%3A8000%2Fjfe%2Fcustomer%2F3%2FKJ%252002%252F2017%2Fportfolio%2F&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0). I also tried the unencoded string with the same result.

Comment: Paulo you are correct. I think the problem is that Django decodes the URL before passing it to the regex.

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875886/django-url-pattern-parameter-with-forward-slash?rq=1) help?

Comment: I encode the URL, but it looks like it gets decoded before going to the URL dispatcher. Maybe using a different character other than '/' as a delimiter will work as shown in your question link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to figure out how to create a regular expression which would capture the arguments when they have a '/'. To get around this problem I double encoded the argument so that way it doesn't get completely decoded when going to the URL dispatcher.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
"/[0-9]+(?:-|.|\/)+[a-zA-Z]+(?:-|.|\/)+[0-9]/"
```

Comment: thank you Paddy for the response. I gave it a shot, but wasnt able to have the URL pattern recognized. This was what it looked like: url(r'^customer/(?P<customer_number>[0-9]+)/(?P<invoice>[0-9]+(?:-|.|\/)+[a-zA-Z]+(?:-|.|\/)+[0-9])/(?P<portfolio>[^/]+)/$')